# what is the logic behind for loop in this program to convert binary number to decimal number

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void) 
{
  int bit,i,n ;
  unsigned long decimal=0;
  char binary[33];
  printf("input binary number");
  scanf("%32s",binary);
  n=strlen(binary);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    bit=binary[i]-'0';
    decimal=(decimal<<1)+bit;

    }
  printf("decimal of %s is %lu",binary,decimal);

return 0;
 }
```

program to convert binary number to decimal.program is working perfectly but i don`t understand the logic behind for loop.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? [Bit manipulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation)?

Comment: The `for` loop is simply iterating over the binary digits entered. What is confusing you?

Comment: BTW, it may work correctly for correct input. But you'll get very interesting results if you enter any non-binary digits or alpha characters, for example.

Comment: thanku very much i really appreciate  but i don`t understand statement - (decimal<<1)+bit   here,as you said for loop is iterating over binary digits

Comment: yea,it is really interesting ,i tried

Comment: This code converts "ASCII string representing a number in binary" into an integer. It doesn't convert to decimal at all. The code to do the "integer to ASCII string representing a number in decimal" part is done by the standard library (as part of the `printf()`).

Comment: Could use `if (scanf(" %32[01]",binary) != 1) Error();` to avoid trouble with digits 2-9, A-Z etc.  (@Fred Larson concern)

Comment: yea ..  if would be better

Answer (score 1):

for example, the input is "110" which is ‘1’ ‘1’ ‘0’ in the array

**1st loop:  with decimal = 0**

bit = '1' - '0' = 1

decimal = (0<<1) + bit = 1

**2nd loop: with dcimal = 1**

bit = '1' - '0' = 1

decimal = (1<<1) + bit =  b(10) + 1 = b(11)

**3rd loop: with dcimal = b(11)**

bit = '0' - '0' = 0

decimal = (b(11)<<1) + bit =  b(110) + 0 = b(110)

Answer (score 0):

Every digit of a number in a certain base represents a quantity proportional to base risen to the power of the digit's position.

For example, the number 86 represents the sum of 6 * 10^0 (as 6 is in the units positions, digit "index" of 0) and 8 * 10^1 (as 8 is in the tens position). 80 + 6 is unsurprisingly, 86.

The same rule applies for binary numbers.

The binary number 0011 represents the sum of 1 * 2^0 + 1 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^2 + 0 * 2^3 + ... = 3 (in base 10 decimal)

The for loop in the function is used to iterate over each digit/bit and summing the total value of that particular digit to the unsigned long named `decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `binary` is a string (an array of characters) and when you get your input:

```
scanf("%32s",binary);
```

You're getting characters that represent numbers. Meaning if you look at the [acii](http://www.asciitable.com/) representations of characters you'll see that:

'0' is 48<sub>10</sub>
'1' is 49<sub>10</sub>
'2' is 50<sub>10</sub>
etc..

So every character number has an integer value that corresponds to it. The `for` loop is looping through the string that was input and getting the actual integer number that was entered by subtracting the character `'0'`:

```
// example to better explain the idea:
int zero = '0' - '0';  // 48 - 48
int one = '1' - '0';   // 49 - 48
```

Once the actual value (1 or 0) is known then the value is shifted into place with the last line in the loop:

```
decimal=(decimal<<1)+bit;
```

The first time through you'll have 0 shifted to the left by 1 (which is still 0) then you add to that `bit` which will be 0 or 1.

so say you have the string "101" entered, first pass you'll have:

```
bit = '1' - '0'; // 1
decimal = (0 << 1) + 1; // 1
```

next:

```
bit = '0' - '0'; // 0
decimal = (1 << 1) + 0; // 10
```

finally:

```
bit = '1' - '0'; // 1
decimal = (10 << 1) + 1; // 101
```